# Different java versions on client for different java web start applications

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have 3 different java web start applications with different requirements on jvm version on the client desktop to be able to work. One is 1.5 and two have different 1.6.x requirements. My experience is that depending on what java version you installed last some applications will work and others not.

Is there a way to ensure that all 3 will work?

Thanks.

Comment: You explicitly request an appropriate Java version in your JNLP-file?

Comment: change the configuration of applications according to the java version

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the JAVAWS to run the application in Java 1.5 mode by installing the higher version required by any one of the application.

[VM properties for JVM](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart/faq.html#41)

[JNLP Syntax to configure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to ensure that all 3 will work?

Yes.

> One is 1.5 ..

```
<j2se version='1.5*'>
```

> ..two have different 1.6.x requirements.

See [Java Web Start - Runtime Versioning](http://pscode.org/jws/version.html) for more details.